# if $\frac{1+f'(x)^{2}+f''(x)^{2}}{(1+f'(x)^{2})^{3}}=c$, $f(x)$ is only linear function of $x$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Define a smooth function $f(x)$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)$ is the first order derivative and $f''(x)$ is the second order derivative.

The $f(x)$ satisfies:
$$\frac{1+f'(x)^{2}+f''(x)^{2}}{(1+f'(x)^{2})^{3}}=c$$
where c is a constant.

How can I prove that $f(x)$ must be a linear function of $x$? For example, $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x$?

Comment: What did you try? What courses are you taking?

Comment: this is a general problem, given a filament on a cylinder, if the curvature of every point on the filament is a constant, then I guess the filament must be helical. But I do not know how to prove this.